# Possible to guarantee a scope in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I'm building an API with "live" and "test" environments.  I'm currently accomplishing this by adding an "environment" column on each of my models.

When I create objects, I use a validator to guarantee that the "environment" column is set.

I want to do something similar when retrieving objects.  When someone makes a GET request for a list of objects, I want to guarantee, ideally at the Model level, that only "live" or only "test" objects are returned.  It should never have both.

(I just want a way to prevent myself from forgetting to add a `where(environment: @env)` on ActiveRecord lookups...this will be used in combination with a test suite.)

Comment: Sure, set a default scope, as in the Rails docs. Personally, however, I think an "environment" would be better served by a different DB.

Comment: What is your recommendation using default_scope?  Good suggestion about another DB - I'll definitely consider it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's a hack but I found something I'm moderately happy with:

```
default_scope { where(:fakecolumn=>nil) }
scope :environment, ->(env) { unscope(where: :fakecolumn).where(:livemode=>env.livemode) }
```

This sets the default scope to search for `Model.fakecolumn`, which raises an exception because `fakecolumn` does not exist.

My custom `:environment` scope unsets the dummy column, so the exception goes away.

Not a great solution, but it's certainly better than overriding `find`